# CASE: choose value in column B base on condition in column A

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table with values. Values are duplicated based on values in column B (different views on data). I can't seem to select a value based on a condition (if value in column A starts with XX or YY, then choose FIN else choose PO)

I tried "if" and "case" but can't get anything to work

```
Table

Code Geoview Metric         
XX1000  FIN 10
XX1000  PO  10
YY1800  FIN 20
YY1800  PO  20
TT2000  PO  35
TT2500  PO  50



`CASE 
    WHEN [Code] = '%XX' and [Code] = '%YY' 
    THEN [Geoview] = 'FIN' 
    ELSE [Geoview] = 'PO' 
    END`
```

If code starts with XX or YY then return row with FIN in geo view otherwise get PO (only FIN or PO as available values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CASE to create complex relational conditions in your predicate but for performance purposes it might be better to code it in a more straight forward way.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table
  WHERE  
       ( CASE 
          WHEN left(code,2) IN ('XX', 'YY') and geoview = 'PO'  THEN 0
          WHEN left(code,2) IN ('XX', 'YY') and geoview = 'FIN' THEN 1 
          WHEN geoview = 'PO' THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END ) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) and this pattern `'XX%'` which means starting with `'XX'`:

```
select 
  Code,  
  CASE 
    WHEN Code LIKE 'XX%' OR Code LIKE 'YY%' THEN 'FIN' 
    ELSE 'PO' 
  END Geoview,
  Metric
FROM mytable
```

or with [`LEFT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left):

```
select 
  Code,  
  CASE 
    WHEN LEFT(Code, 2) IN ('XX', 'YY') THEN 'FIN' 
    ELSE 'PO' 
  END Geoview,
  Metric
FROM mytable
```

Comment: I Like two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

for string starting with XX or YY use `LIKE XX%` and `LIKE YY%`

and for check both use OR instead of AND

```
CASE 
   WHEN [Code] LIKE 'XX%' OR [Code] LIKE  'YY%' 
    THEN [Geoview] = 'FIN' 
    ELSE [Geoview] = 'PO' 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
      select code,case when code like '%XX' or '%YY'
       then 'FIN' 
       else 'PO' emd as geo from table_name
```